Can't see any previous solution for this: E-mail setting on Stack Exchange refuses to change
Here, on Stack Exchange. Attempting to change ancient e-mail setting to newer one. No longer have access to the old e-mail address. It took the change (as far as I can see) to the new one for logins, but it still lists the old e-mail address in the "e-mail settings" profile section. I change it, hit "save", it says beneath it, "change taken", but instantly reverts it to the old email provider's domain info. What the heck?
I've tried logging out, restarting, etc., no change in result. Still shows old email address.
I searched for info in the help section, nothing I found dealt with this. Seems unlikely to be aimed only at me, but odd that there is nothing I saw in “Help” that appeared to be about resolving this.
It did revise the login, as far as I can tell, but I presume it would still send any info e-mails to the moribund email address.

What's your account? It's suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account with new credential to check if there are some differences.

If all else fails - its probably worth using contact us, and getting in touch with support.

Yeah. Use the contact form, that's probably your best bet to get your account access restored.
